# Understanding 'few illusions are harder to shed'

Tags: sentence-meaning

Below is the sentence from an article "What the World Will Speak in 2115" from Wall Street Journal.

> Few illusions are harder to shed than the idea that only writing makes
>   something a language.

What I think is that here illusions and an idea is compared. But I don't understand what writer meant when he said, 'few illusions are harder to shed'.

Comment: What is your problem here? What do you not understand?

Comment: We are  not a translation service: Without more details about what you *did* or *didn't* understand we can't help you.

Comment: Okay, that sentence appears in the Wall Street Journal. I'll take your word for it. :-) What about it?

Comment: The author's view is that some people consider a language to be a *real* language  only when its users also compose written texts in it.  He regards that view as misguided, and implies that those who hold the view hold onto it stubbornly, and refuse to be enlightened. The word "shed" means to cast off, like a dead skin, or rainwater from a roof.

Comment: @TRomano You should write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, an "illusion" is "belief in something that's not true".

To "shed" something is to get rid of it.  The word is most appropriate when the thing you're getting rid of is attached to you - snakes shed their skin, cats shed their hair, etc.  Ideas (true or false) are metaphorically "attached to" us.

To shed an illusion is to stop believing in something that's not true.

If you're particularly attached to an illusion - if an illusion is important to you - then it will be "difficult to shed".

Some illusions are more difficult to shed than others.  If "few illusions are more difficult to shed" than X, then X is a particularly difficult illusion to shed - that is, people who believe X have a particularly hard time *stopping* believing X.